# Grails: How to exclude ApplicationHttpRequest field in converting a domain class to JSON

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I want to convert my domain classes to JSON format. But during the conversion, I've encountered this issue below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: Error converting Bean with class org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: Error converting Bean with class org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:202)
at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:162)
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:202)
at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:162)
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:202)
at grails.converters.JSON.render(JSON.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller can not access a member of class org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest with modifiers "public"
```

I used JSON converters to convert Object to JSON format.

```
render myDomain as JSON
```

These are the domain classes of my app.

```
MyDomain {

    String username
    String password
    ApplicationHttpRequest request
    OtherDomain otherDomain
}

OtherDomain {
    String otherField1
    String otherFiled2
    ApplicationHttpRequest request
}
```

I really wanted to convert objects to json excluding the request field above. How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: It does not make sense to have a persistent property referencing an http request.

Comment: Jeff is right. You should pass the properties of the request you want as an storable object/string (preferably not a blob). Convert to a JSON string or serialized string if possible or (IDEALLY) create a separate table with all the separate vars as tuples/rows.